# multiple function exection on window scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using Couple of Main div Inside each main div I am calling few more sub div which have some class file defined in my CSS. All these class file include images on it.I am implying window scroll effect since my page is single page with lots of images.I done some research on google but did not find suitable answer.While scrolling the page I need to remove some class from page scroll,for which I am going to use jquery removeClass().I have some function on window scroll method.Now on window.sroll() effect only I want to delete some class while page is scrolling down.

I looking for answer like how to use multiple function on window scroll.How to bind two or three function on window.scroll. How to execute multiple function on window scroll.
HTML

```
$(window).scroll(function () {        
        if ($("#first").offset().top + $("#first").height() < $(document).scrollTop()) {
            var obj = $('#first').children('div');
            if (obj.hasClass("d")) {
                obj.removeClass();
            }
            obj = obj.children('div');
            if (obj.hasClass("c")) {
                obj.removeClass();
            }
            obj = obj.children('div');
            if (obj.hasClass("e")) {
                obj.removeClass();
            }
        } else {
            var obj = $('#first').children('div');
            if (obj.hasClass("d") == false) {
                obj.addClass("d");
            }
            obj = obj.children('div');
            if (obj.hasClass("c") == false) {
                obj.addClass("c");
            }
            obj = obj.children('div');
            if (obj.hasClass("e") == false) {
                obj.addClass("e");
            }
        }
<div id="firstMain">
<div class"a"> </div>
<div class"b"> </div>
<div class"c"> </div>
</div>
<div id="Second"></div>
<div id="Z"></div>
```

Comment: You can add multiple handlers to the event. Or you can just call multiple functions from the handler that you've already added :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add multiple handlers, they will be executed in the order you add them.

```
$(window).scroll(scrollHandlerOne);
$(window).scroll(scrollHandlerTwo);

function scrollHandlerOne(e) {
  // Do logic here
  // Executed first
}

function scrollHandlerTwo(e) {
  // Do logic here    
  // Executed second
}
```